# Why is a variable in __init__() method not defined in the subclass?

Tags: python, class, subclass, object-oriented-analysis

In subclass `ComputerGame`, `Toy.__init__(self,n)`,  `n` is undefined.

Why is it warning me that the variable `n` is undefined when I try to call the `__init__()` function in the base class? Simply put, why is `Toy.__init__(self,n)` not callable in the subclass? I have declared `ComputerGame (Toy):`. Why isn't it inheriting the method `Toy.__init__(self,n)`?

Should I declare the variable outside the class?

```
class Toy:
  def __init__(self,n):
    self.__ToyName = n
    self.__ToyID = ""
    self.__Price = 0.00
    self.__MinimumAge = 4

  def SetToyName(self,p):
    self.__ToyName = p
  def SetToyID(self,d):
    self.__ToyID = d
  def SetPrice(self,i):
    self.__Price = i
  def SetMinimumAge(self,i):
    self.__MinimumAge = i
  def GetToyName(self):
    return (self.__ToyName)
  def GetToyID(self):
    return (self.__ToyID)
  def GetPrice(self):
    return (self.__Price)
  def GetMinimumAge(self):
    return (self.__MinimumAge)


class ComputerGame(Toy):
  def __init__(self):
    Toy.__init__(self,n)
    self.__Catogory = ""
    self.__Console = ""

  def SetCatogory(self,c):
    self.__Catogory = c
  def SetConsole(self,c):
    self.__Console = c
  def GetCatogory(self):
    return (self.__Catogory)
  def GetConsole(self):
    return (self.__Console)
```

Comment: `n` is the argument to your `__init__()` function. The member variables are those that are prefixed with `self`

Answer (score 1):

This is a scoping issue:

```
class ComputerGame(Toy):
  def __init__(self):
    Toy.__init__(self,n)
```

This is the first appearance of `n`.  When you create a `ComputerGame`, your `__init__` methods requires you (the calling program) to supply `n` as part of the creation.  That's how *you* wrote the code.

The `__init__` above assumes that `n` will appear magically from nowhere.  I'm unclear what data flow you expect from this -- and so is the Python compiler.  I don't know how to fix this for you, since you failed to supply a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We should have at least one line of main code to create the object.

One strong possibility is fairly simple:

```
class ComputerGame(Toy):
  def __init__(self, n):
    Toy.__init__(self, n)
```

NewFPS = ComputerGame("Universal Uzi")

Does that clear it up?

Comment: Appreciate it! Does it mean when I create a "ComputerGame", I will have to supply all the variables in the "Toy" as part of the creation?

Comment: No, only the ones required for initialization.  For the code you've written, this is only `n`.  The others are handled by `Set<feature>` methods.

Comment: Got it ! Thanks!